# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219: in laravel after successfully payment in paypal

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

Browser displays me this error when i use post method:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:

my route

```
Route::post('/paypalpostback', 'User\UserController@newUserPaypal');
```

if i use get method no error but no data return from paypal

Please help me how to fix this error and how to get data from paypal

Comment: I can't remind me exactly but I think the callback is called using GET http method. Try to change Route::post with Route::get ?

Comment: i try both methods but in post method show me error and in get method no error but no get any data from paypal

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, you are binding the route to the wrong http method. In fact paypal is sending the callback using GET method. Thus you are getting a wrong method exception because the route is registered using post.

To fix this specific error, simply change the Route::post by Route::get. Alternatively you can use Route::any to make the http verb irrelevant when routing.

As of why you don't get any data from paypal, well maybe you arn't reading it the way they intend it to be read. May I suggest you to start digging that problem with dd(Input::all()) and post another question on that matter.